# I got the error javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I hope this time somebody can help me with this issue. I´m currently developing a web app which is built using EJB + JPA  and at the end all i got is the error message: javax.ejb.EJBException and such error points out to the line 25 in the DAO local interface and also in line 31 in the class i named SessionLogin located into the package com.javarevolutions.ejb.bean into the EJB module. My questions is why does it say that the query named "Login.findByLoginAndPassword" isn't focused through out the error message

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Here my code to get a better understanding of my problem:

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy405.validaDatos(Unknown Source)
at com.javarevolutions.ejb.bean.__EJB31_Generated__SessionLogin__Intf____Bean__.validaDatos(Unknown Source)
at com.javarevolutions.jsf.bean.BeanLogin.validarLogin(BeanLogin.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.javarevolutions.ejb.dao.DAOLoginImpl.existUser(DAOLoginImpl.java:25)
at com.javarevolutions.ejb.bean.SessionLogin.validaDatos(SessionLogin.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor175.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4667)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4655)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 50 more
```

thanks in advance for the hint you can give me.

Note: This is my 2nd. inquiry i made in the forum and nobody gave me a single answer  but i already solve the last issue.

:(

public class DAOLoginImpl implements DAOLogin {

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Override
public boolean existUser(Login entity) {

    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Login.findByLoginAndPassword");
    query.setParameter("usuario", entity.getUsuario());
    query.setParameter("contrasenia", entity.getPassword());
    if (query.getSingleResult() != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
@Stateless
```

@LocalBean
public class SessionLogin {

```
public boolean validaDatos(VOLogin vo) {

    System.out.println("User : " + vo.getUsuario());
    System.out.println("Password : " + vo.getContrasenia());
    DAOLogin dao = new DAOLoginImpl();
    Login entity = new Login();
    entity.setUsuario(vo.getUsuario());
    entity.setPassword(vo.getContrasenia());
    return dao.existUser(entity);

    }
```

}

```
public Login() {
}

public Login(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Login(String usuario, String password, String nombre, int edad) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.password = password;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (usuario != null ? usuario.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Login)) {
        return false;
    }
    Login other = (Login) object;
    if ((this.usuario == null && other.usuario != null) || (this.usuario != null && !this.usuario.equals(other.usuario))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.javarevolutions.ejb.entities.Login[ usuario=" + usuario + " ]";
}
```

}
code here

Answer (score 0):

As your code says, it's a `NullPointerException`, that means somewhere inside `DAOLoginImpl` you are trying to use a null object.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.javarevolutions.ejb.dao.DAOLoginImpl.existUser(DAOLoginImpl.java:25)
```

To make this work correctly, make sure to check for null objects before using them.

Comment: thanks Roque. However this is the part where i'm lost. How can i find out what could be the null objects. According to the error the line 25 is where the problem is to locate the null object, and this line is where is declared the query name in my case "Login.findByLoginAndPassword" though, when i create the entities from Database, i added a new line as follows;

Comment: , @NamedQuery(name = "Login.findByLoginAndPassword", query = "SELECT l FROM Login l WHERE l.usuario = :usuario and l.password = :contrasenia")

Comment: Post the `DAOLoginImpl.existUser` to the question so I can see he code and help more.

Comment: Thank you roque. i posted for you. :)

Comment: The error is in line 25. What are you doing specifically in that line? Based on you code, it is possible that Login entity is null.

Comment: i add the code which corresponds to a session bean in this case called SessionLogin and this is when Netbeans detects the error in line 25 and Login class is the EJB itself.

Comment: Debug the code and navigate inside de existUser method to see which object is null.. You can be more accurate if you put the breakpoint in line 25 inside the existUser method.